# CentOS 5.8 ISO with custom packages

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum

How can I create a CentOS 5.8 .iso image with custom packages? I have to create an iso with only the packages needed for our production system. I already have all the rpms with their dependencies resolved in a folder. I have successfully created a repository from that folder with createrepo.

As I understand it, I should put the rpm files in the CentOS folder, and repodata folder should contain the metadata needed for a package manager. I don't know if I should modify the existing comps.xml file or create a new one, or which structure to use, since this is only a subset of packages contained on a default CentOS installation disk.

I know it is probably futile to delete packages from the default iso, but that is my work order and there's not much to be done there. (There are also some packages not available in the default iso)

Much appreciated

Comment: This link might be useful to you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236910/error-while-installing-respinned-customized-centos

Answer (score 1):

I feel as though your question is a bit vague for a topic with this sort of breadth but I'll do my best to offer an answer. I think you should use [Kickstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickstart_%28Linux%29) for this task as it's going to result in a much happier customer whether they're internal or external, and easier management for you going forward when things get updated. Start by reviewing the [CentOS documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-kickstart2.html), if you are already this far and just asking about removing packages, check out [this](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-packageselection.html) section of the docs, it talks about specifying your packages and removing the ones you don't want.

If you only have the one style of production machine, then this should take care of it. if you have multiple different configurations I'd suggest taking a look at a configuration management tool such as [Ansible](http://ansible.cc/), [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), or [Salt](http://docs.saltstack.org/en/latest/contents.html). This would allow you to provide a base image via Kickstart, then build off of that image depending on the needs of whoever is consuming the system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for being vague. The gist of it is this: I have all the rpms of the packages the production server needs. I want to build a custom CentOS installation disk which will contain only those packages and install them all by default. The idea is that an engineer can install it all without using an internet connection on a customers' server, and that the size of the iso is kept small.

Comment: Yea Kickstart would be perfect for what you want to do.