# How to build CentOS ISO with custom packages like vlc,eclipse etc.?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, linux-distro

How can i make an CentOS iso having software packages of my choice,
*i.e. distro having Ganglia,vlc etc.* 
Alternately, say i have installed aforesaid packages on my os,
how to create customised "standalone" iso of this os  so that i can replicate/install the same on other machines in internet connection DISABLED scenario.

kickstart post script solution(HTTP download) is not valid :
[CentOS 5.8 ISO with custom packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588945/centos-5-8-iso-with-custom-packages)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a kickstart file and do all the package installtion in `%post` section refer to thid documnet https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html

Comment: i want a standalone iso , if one does not have internet connection ,
how can the commands download the packages such as vlc, ganglia.
kickstart file is not useful in this scenario.

Comment: yes you have the media CDs which holds the CentOS and you have the kickstartfile either through floppy Disk, USB stick, PXE Boot configuration, HTTP/FTP from local network which i thing it covers all the possibilities to read the kickstart file

Comment: i want to distribute this iso to someone with a laptop,without internet connection. then how come the "kickstart" method installs vlc ,ganglia etc??

Comment: check the following documnet it address copying the kickstartfile to the media cd which contains the CentOS installer https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-putkickstarthere.html or this http://linuxkarthik.blogspot.gr/2011/08/how-to-customize-centos-dvd-using.html

Comment: using this as reference:
https://wikis.uit.tufts.edu/confluence/display/TUSKpub/Build+Custom+RHEL+or+CentOS+Respin+DVD

i customized the ISO by "only copying" some rpm packages in /Packages directory
$$$
booting ISO via kickstart, i get:
%%% Unable to read package metadata. This may be due to missing repodata directory. Please ensure that your install tree has been correct generated. Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: anaconda-based-20003220802.x86_64. Please verify its path and try again.%%%%%%%
any idea where all this is going wrong ?

Comment: do you have a directive in the kisckstart file like this `repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl=` if yes remove this line since the kickstartfile resides on the same iso or cd

Comment: yes i did that yesterday ,here is the error after removing the line.
error remains same ,weather i add or remove the line.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236910/error-while-installing-respinned-customized-centos