# error while installing respinned/customized centos

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, redhat, linux-distro

i am following this link with an aim to create custom CentOS ISO with some extra packages downloaded from internet (say ABCD.rpm).
https://wikis.uit.tufts.edu/confluence/display/TUSKpub/Build+Custom+RHEL+or+CentOS+Respin+DVD
i customized the ISO by "only copying" ABCD.rpm package in /Packages directory

now when i boot from ISO via kickstart, i get following error
[image]

any idea where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue. It is working fine after using the following command to create ISO.

```
mkisofs -r -N -L -d -J -T -joliet-long -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -V RHEL6.5 -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o RHEL6.5-20131111.0-Server-x86_64-DVD1_new3.iso RHEL6.5-20131111.0-Server-x86_64-DVD1_new
```

Comment: rebuilt iso with the flags you mentioned ,on booting iso from vmware   :-   
##if i **do not include** extra packages then iso boots fine, and ##if extra packages **are included** then on welcome screen getting error: "_The CentOS disc was not found in any of your CD ROM Drives.Please insert centos disk and press ok to retry_"

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-create the comps.xml for any new added package.

```
cd <your_working_path>/isolinux
createrepo -u "media://`head -1 .discinfo`" -g <your_working_path>/comps.xml .
```

Comment: This suggestion was tried,
and the error still was the same.

Trying to build centos 6.4 (all tutorials/documents on web are for previous versions) please try building the same if you can,and please share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add '-joliet-long' option to mkisofs.
These file name under the /repodata is too long.

Comment: This suggestion was tried,got same error.Please try building the iso if you can,and share your experience.